# Multinom package in r , but some participants with multiple observations

Tags: r, multinomial-logit

I am conducting a multinomial regression using multinom package in r. Outcome is the day the week a patient was discharged (7 levels) and there are a few predictors that are not choice-specific (age, sex, etc). However, I have some patients who had multiple observations. How can I address with multinom? I don’t think I can add random intercepts with multinom. Is there a way to cluster SEs and how? Any recommended approach with multinom is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

R does offer ways to do multilevel multinomial logistic regression. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082396/multinomial-logistic-multilevel-models-in-r) for a good discussion.  However, if only "some" of your patients have multiple observations, then that might not work.

One solution is to just use the first occurrence for each patient. Whether this is acceptable in your case would depend on what exactly you are hypothesizing, what proportion of people have more than one occurrence, and whether those people are markedly different from the singles.

Comment: Peter, do you think clustering SE by participant works? Do you know of a package that can do this after multinom?

Comment: I am not at all sure if it would work, maybe.  I don't know of such a package.

Comment: Should be able to obtain cluster-adjusted SEs for a `multinom` model object using the *sandwich* package on CRAN or, what might be easier, the wrapper for it in the *parameters* package also on CRAN.

Comment: Thank you jluchman. It seems that packages that cluster SE such as sandwich do not accept  the output of multinom.